# Can anyone explain recursive in Nth fibonacci?

Tags: javascript

I was doing a coding algorithm to find the nth number which is the sum of the (n-1)th and (n-2)th numbers.

Here was the solution

```
function getNthFib(n, hashTable = {1: 0, 2: 1}) {
  if (n in hashTable) {
    return hashTable[n]
  } else {
    hashTable[n] = getNthFib(n - 1, hashTable) + getNthFib(n - 2, hashTable)
    return hashTable[n]
  }
}
```

can anyone explain to me in the else block of what is actually happening? i am confused with this recursive concept

Comment: I'd recommend the [Khan Academy video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg-ddPbzcKM). The code you've shown includes a hash table for memoization which makes the solution a little more complex than usual, but if you understand the video, you'll understand the basic code. After that, you can read about memoization.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive Fibonacci works beacse the next number is the last two numbers combined. Eg 3 + 5 = 8 and then 5 + 8 = 13. The recursive solution finds the value of the 2 numbers to add to the next, and then finds the numbers before, etc. The hashtable, which is a plain object, maps precomputed values so it does not have to compute them again, as recursive Fibonacci has a O(n!) time complexity without a table or cache.